# body class not working

Tags: javascript, css

Basically what I'm trying to do is this ... I have a site that I want to make change the background day or night ... so day one thing((till around 7pm or so)) and then night till around 7 am or so .. I have a script in place that changes the class of my body tag to reflect two different body elements in my CSS page ..

```
.night body {
    font-size:18px;
    color:#999;
    background-image:url(nightwolfwall.jpg);
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-color: #000; 
}
.day body {
    font-size:18px;
    color:#999;
    background-image:url(daywolfwall.jpg);
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-color: #000; 
}
```

but for the life of me .. I cannot get them to work .. I've even tried to change the class of the body tag manually to test the class ids .. and nothing .. am I doing something wrong in the css?

Answer (score 3):

```
.day body{
```

Should be

```
body.day{
```

- The first one applies to the `<body>` which is inside an element with the class `day`
- Mine  applies  to `<body>` with the `day` class.

So as for:

```
.night body{
```

Should be:

```
body.night{
```

Comment: @NULL ;) Way ahead by 9 seconds of Kos. :)

Comment: Or as I look at it: 5 posts on SO. (`13193781-13193776 = 5 posts before`)

Answer (score 2):

Use `body.day` and `body.night` selectors instead.

`.day body` means a `body` tag nested under any tag with class `day`.

Answer (score 2):

You are using [descendant selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#descendant-selectors) which mean "A body element that is a descendant of an element (of any type) that is a member of night/day".

To match a body element that *is* a member of a class:

```
body.classname
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
body.night {
```

to select the `body` of class `night`.

Answer (score 1):

`body.night {
/* CODE */
}`

`body.day{
/* CODE */
}`

CSS rules are basically written hierarchical. The most abstract element left and the most specific right. In other words, an element that is inside another is always right from the former.

When a class is assigned to an element, you write the class connected to the element (same with ID's) and **not** with a space in between.

`body.day` is **not** the same as `body .day`. The later targets an element inside `body` that has a class `day`. This can be any element.

Also note that there is no restriction on how deep an element can be when using this code. For example: `body .day` has loads of possible HTML structures. For example:

```
<body>
  <div class="day">
  </div>
</body>
```

But also:

```
<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div class="day">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Note:** you can select only [direct children](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors) of an element by using `>` e.g. `body > div.test` will only target divs that are immediately inside `body` and that have a class `test`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a class of "night" on your body tag then you should reference it in your CSS like so:

```
body.night {
// css styles
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give this way:

```
body.night {}
body.day {}
```

In the way you give right now, it can be applied for the `<html>` tag. So, giving this way:

```
<html class="day">

<html class="night">
```

Works in this case. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Body tag doesn't have any enclosing tag other than html so your css class should be

CSS

```
body {
   margin:0;
   /* other property */
}

.night {
    background:#000;
}
```

HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body class="night">
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your css to

```
body.night { ... }
```

or add your night/day classes to html element instead.

Comment: Why would you add an answer after there are many valid answers saying the same thing for couple of minutes?

Comment: You might want to notice that my answer offers 2 options as opposed to other replies.